# Add the respective elements of each list in a dictionary of lists and store the results into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having the dictionary of lists:

```
 percent = {'l1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'l2': [-16, -16, -16, -16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'l3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'l4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'l5': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       'l6': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -16, 0, 0],
       'l7': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -48],
       'l8': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12, -20]
       }
```

I want to add the first elements of all the lists and store the result as a first element of list result = [] and respectively for other elements?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you mean 0+(-16)+0+0+............?

Comment: Yes. I want these for all the elements...

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external modules this can be done in a very simple manner. As there are 9 elements in the values for all distinct keys, it involves simple iteration:

```
result = []

for i in range(9):
    total = 0
    for key,value in percent.items():
        # On each iteration, it selects the `ith` element from each list and adds to `total` variable.
        total += value[i]
    result.append(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write this as a nested list comprehension:

```
results = [sum([l[i] for l in percent.values()]) 
           for i in range(len(list(percent.values())[0]))]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
results = []

for i in range(len(list(percent.values())[0])):
    s = 0
    for l in percent.values():
        s += l[i]
    results.append(s)
```

`len(list(percent.values())[0])` is used to find the length of the lists in the dictionary dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*percent.values())]
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to that code? For example, what's that `*` needed for?

Comment: This is the best solution here :) This can also be generalized in case you want to add empty column for too-short rows: [sum(x) for x in itertools.zip_longest(*percent.values(), fillvalue=0)]

Comment: @NicoHaase, The "`*`" converts the list/iterable into an argument list. See here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html or here: https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with list comprehension:

```
# length of first element
length = len(list(percent.values())[0])
sums = [sum(val[i] for val in percent.values()) for i in range(length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
narr = np.asarray(list(percent.values()))
result = narr.sum(0)
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning!! but these are just some direct functions how i can explain them. plz provide an example, the kind of explanation expected here.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the length of each list, a list comprehension-based solution would look like this:

```
percent['result'] = [sum(v[i] for v in percent.values()) 
                     for i in range(9)]
```

If you do not, you might look at the first element of the dict:

```
percent['result'] = [sum(v[i] for v in percent.values())
                     for i in range(len(next(iter(percent.values()))))]
```

However, this is all relatively cumbersome. If you are doing several such mathematical operations, you might want to look into the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) libraries.